# Create function on AWS RDS mysql

Tags: mysql, function, amazon-web-services

I have enabled functions as said in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-functions/

I am trying to create function with following code

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `GETDISTANCE`(deg_lat1 FLOAT, deg_lng1 FLOAT, deg_lat2 FLOAT, deg_lng2 FLOAT) RETURNS float
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
DECLARE earthSphRadKms FLOAT; 
DECLARE lat1Radians FLOAT; 
DECLARE lat2Radians FLOAT; 
DECLARE lon1Radians FLOAT; 
DECLARE lon2Radians FLOAT;
DECLARE distance FLOAT;

SET distance = 0;

SET earthSphRadKms = 6371.0072;
SET lat1Radians = (deg_lat1 / 180) * PI();
SET lon1Radians = (deg_lng1 / 180) * PI();
SET lat2Radians = (deg_lat2 / 180) * PI();
SET lon2Radians = (deg_lng2 / 180) * PI();

SET distance = ROUND(2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((lat1Radians - lat2Radians) / 2) ,2) + COS(lat1Radians) * COS(lat2Radians) * POWER(SIN((lon1Radians - lon2Radians) / 2), 2)))  * (earthSphRadKms * 1), 4);


RETURN distance;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it gives me below error.

**Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER $$ CREATE FUNCTION `GETDISTANCE`(deg_lat1 FLOAT, deg_lng1 FLOAT, deg_' at line 1**

Comment: this function works fine at localhost

Comment: What utility are you using to send this query to the RDS machine?  `DELIMITER` is a *client* directive, and relies on proper handling by the client.  Some, like phpmyadmin, expect you to do this in their own, random, non-standard way.